# Is there a portable way to implement variadic CHECK and PROBE macros for detecting the number of macro arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

In [C Preprocessor tricks, tips, and idioms](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms), it suggests the following macros which detect the number of arguments created by a macro:

```
#define CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__, 0,)
#define PROBE(x) x, 1,
```

and then states that:

```
CHECK(PROBE(~)) // Expands to 1
CHECK(xxx)      // Expands to 0
```

However in MSVC 2019, compiling for C++17, the above two `CHECK()`'s both expand to 0. Godbolt shows me that GCC and Clang  expand the macros as expected, but MSVC does not. It seems to be pasting `__VA_ARGS__` from `CHECK(...)` as a single token even if it contains commas...?

I have heard that MSVC is nonconforming with regard to macros in some ways, but I am not clear on the details.

Is there a way to make these macros work for MSVC, and ideally still work for GCC/Clang? (I'd rather not `#ifdef` a separate implementation if possible.)

Comment: While not a fix for all MSVC versions, they did add what is supposed to be a standards-conformant preprocessor at some point. It has to be specifically enabled with the /Zc:preprocessor project setting/command line argument.

Comment: Actually seems to be independent of `__VA_ARGS__`, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kf8ajPxax). Compiler flag indeed fixes – cannot understand why MS did not make that standard... With this kind of default macro expansion it doesn't appear to me that you'll get a fix for at all (without using the flag) unless skipping the intermediate `PROBE` macro :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I found [this answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-va-args-seems-to-be-trated-as-a-single-parameter/460154) from the VS Developer Community, which provides the solution: an extra layer of indirection and some funky rebracketing. Rewriting to match the original question:

```
#define CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define CHECK_IMPL(tuple) CHECK_N tuple         //note no brackets here
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_IMPL((__VA_ARGS__, 0)) //note the double brackets here
#define PROBE(x) x, 1
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4nKc8dM5e) demonstrates that this works across MSVC, gcc, and clang. Some of the other macro tools from the original link also require some adjustments (eg `IIF(x)`) but again, more layers of indirection seem to solve those too.

I hope one day to be able to use the compiler option **/Zc:preprocessor** as was mentioned elsewhere, which also fixes these macros, unfortunately that breaks certain other libraries (such as the Windows SDK).

Comment: Sidenote: This works by forcing the preprocessor to do another scan - the tuple will be scanned twice: once as argument to `CHECK_IMPL` and another time when evaluting the body of `CHECK_IMPL`. Another way to force multiple scans would be [deferred expressions](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#deferred-expression) , e.g. `#define CHECK(...) EXPAND(DEFER(CHECK_N)(__VA_ARGS__, 0,))` [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sqq6bhWY9), which produces the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/variadic-macros?view=msvc-170) carefully, which mentions

> The traditional Microsoft C++ implementation suppresses a trailing
> comma if no arguments are passed to the ellipsis. When the
> /Zc:preprocessor compiler option is set, the trailing comma isn't
> suppressed.

Opening **/Zc:preprocessor** requires the following steps:

1.Open the project's **Property Pages** dialog box.

2.Select the **Configuration Properties** > **C/C++** > **Preprocessor** property page.

3.Modify the **Use Standard Conforming Preprocessor** property and then choose Yes.

I tested with the following code and got the expected result:

```
#define CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__, 0,)
#define PROBE(x) x, 1
#define IS_PAREN(x) CHECK(IS_PAREN_PROBE x)
#define IS_PAREN_PROBE(...) PROBE(~)


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << CHECK(PROBE(~)) << endl;
    cout << CHECK(xxx) << endl;
    cout << IS_PAREN(()) << endl;
        cout << IS_PAREN(xxx) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Philosophically, I think this compiler option is a good solution (especially when writing portable code!) unfortunately the Windows SDK  headers do not compile with this option set, which prevents me from using it.